# null в random.value

Tags: sql, oracle

Может ли функция dbms_random.value возвращать значение null? Если да, то в каких случаях?

Comment: Не может конечно

Comment: Я бы не стал так сразу с плеча-то)

Comment: @Mike сразу ответ писать или дать время для размышлений?

Comment: Я сомневаюсь как в полезности вопроса так и ответа для кого либо. Если value использовать как функцию, то как и большинство функций оракл она вернет NULL если один из параметров null. Но это общепринятое поведение функций, конкретно к dbms_random не имеющее никакого отношения. А если без параметров ее вызывать - то ясно что если она вернет null - то это будет баг ибо в документации на нее сказано что она возвращает случайное значение между 0 и 1. NULL не является числом в этом диапазоне

Answer (score -2):

На самом деле, это пояснение к тому, почему данная функция используется в connect by для парсинга строк. `prior dbms_random.value is not null` — граничное условие рекурсии/парсинга. Именно из-за отсутствия граничного условия происходит зацикливание. Как это доказать:

```
select 
      PRIOR dbms_random.value
from dual x
where PRIOR dbms_random.value is null
connect by level <= length(regexp_replace('some text. more', '[^!?.]+')) + 1
                     AND PRIOR dbms_random.value IS NOT NULL`
```

Данный запрос выдает строку, в которой value is null.

Comment: А причем тут dbms_random ? Это объявленное в документации поведение PRIOR - оно возвращает NULL в том случае если для данной строки не было предыдущей в рекурсии. Точно так же NULL вернется вместо 1 в запросе `select X, PRIOR X from (select 1 X from DUAL) connect by level<3` для первой строки

Comment: А что касается использования в connect by то никого значение не волнует. главное, что оно уникально для каждой новой итерации. А на is null оно проверяется только по тому что на что то его надо было проверять. точно так же можно было бы написать что оно не равно 2, например (потому как числом 2 оно так же не может быть как и NULL)

Comment: И даже круче пример `select prior 1 from DUAL connect by level<3` в первой строке 1 становится NULL ...

Comment: Да, но мы не можем использовать знание о том, что 1 превращается в null. А у меня по крайней мере возникал вопрос, прочему мы используем random в connect by и зачем нам условие is not null, если рандом null не возвращает

Comment: Возможно я неправильно задал вопрос, но ответ содержит практические знания. Кто использует dbms_random.value для парсинга строк, должен понимать, как это работает

Comment: Как это работает я описал в ответе на ваш комментарий в другом вопросе. Это работает не за счет того null он или нет. А за чес того, что оракл при проверки на дубли убеждается что в предыдущей строке рекурсии есть хотя бы одно отличное от текущей строки значение для какой либо колонки используемой с prior и random для этой цели подходит так как в каждой строке дает другое значение. И это не граничное условие - оно всегда истинно. граничное вы сами задаете, например указав, что regexp_substr не null. Если вы своего условия не зададите - получите бесконечную рекурсию

Comment: @daydark вам не кажется, что ваш ответ никак не отвечает на поставленный вами же вопрос?